# SharePoint Online Audit - Read / View / Download?

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

In SharePoint Online, there is this

> Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed item properties (This event is not available for SharePoint Online sites)

Is there anyway to circumvent this? For example, a SharePoint List + Javascript on Page Layout that reads the ID and Title and store it for total # of clicks? This will probably affect loading of page / storage, but I can't think of anyway to do this currently.

Is there a better way to do it? I just want to know for example, most popular items in a Document Library or most popular items in the Pages Library.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could write CSR - Client Side Rendering code and attach it with a JSlink on every View;

You can then capture each click on a link and write the `Title` to another SharePoint list (user is the default `Created By` field, timestamp is `Created`)